# Spring Boot RewritePath Replacement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

```
server.port= 8888
spring.application.name=my-api

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id = my-api
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = https://my-api.com
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/services/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/my/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}?d=json
```

I want my routes to look like this:

```
https://localhost:8888/my/users
```

and also here's a fixed query string

```
?d=json
```

so it will be like this

```
https://localhost:8888/my/users
https://localhost:8888/my/books
```

but always I get a "not found" error. Is there a way to rewrite the path to be what I want?

Because if U access the service like this:

```
https://localhost:8888/services/books?d=json
https://localhost:8888/services/users?d=json
```

it has no problem

Thanks in advance